# How to pass na.rm=TRUE to circ.mean {CircStats}?

Tags: r

I am trying to plot the average of the wind direction(in degrees) with the package CircStats. And i have several missing values `NA` in my dataset. And this is the problem I am facing.

```
# Let us convert degrees into radians    
windRad <- rad(x$V1) # x is the dataset and direction is in the first column V1 
circ.mean(windRad)
[1] NA
circ.mean(windRad, na.rm=TRUE)
  Error in circ.mean(windRad, na.rm = TRUE) : 
  unused argument (na.rm = TRUE)
```

Comment: That error usually means that `na.rm` is not an argument to `circ.mean`.  Have you checked the help file? `circ.mean(na.omit(windRad))`might work for you.

Comment: Thanks, this helps. :)

Comment: perhaps try using `na.omit` here or `x$V1[!is.na(x$V1)]`